# Swift lag and double node count

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code to spawn blocks every second.

```
_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnPipes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



func spawnPipes() {

let square = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
square.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
square.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
square.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
self.addChild(square)
```

When i run the code on my iPhone 6, it shows 316 nodes, but on the simulator it shows 158 nodes. Why are there double the nodes on my iPhone?

Its creating lag :( and reduce FPS.

Comment: Which iOS version is installed on your device and which one can be found on your Simulator ? Are you sure that same iOS version is used for testing on both simulator and  device ?

Comment: This may not fix the issue but try to use `SKAction` to spawn nodes instead of `NSTimer` in SpriteKit.

Comment: Could it just be that you've let the app run twice as long?  (Or it runs twice as long before it grinds to a halt?)  If not, you might look at when you are triggering the timer.  Maybe you've got two timers running.  Stick a print() statement in there to see how many times it's getting called in each context.

Comment: Thanks guys. I managed to fix the node count. It now shows 157 nodes on my device. However, the FPS drop from 60fps to 45fps and stays there. 

I don't know why this is happening, I think I might have a memory leak inside when I am generating my sprites or with the NSTimer